# Is it overpowered to allow a Paladin in a 3.5e game to use the Pathfinder 1e version of Smite Evil?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, paladin, duration

Is it overpowered to allow a Paladin in a DnD 3.5 game to use the [Pathfinder 1st Edition version of Smite Evil](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/Core-Classes/Paladin/#Smite_Evil_Su)? It lasts the whole combat rather than just the selected attack.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, this is the norm in all of my games, and it is a significant improvement for those who actually want to play paladins.¹ The paladin was drastically underpowered in 3.5e, and it probably represents the best single change in Pathfinder.² You should use the Pathfinder paladin wholesale.

That said, neither the 3.5e paladin nor the Pathfinder paladin is all that good. Divine grace is one of the best class features in the game, and might even be overpowered, but you get that at 2nd and there is very, very little good reason to take more levels in the class in either game. Far more in Pathfinder,³ but you’re still much better off multiclassing.⁴

The best update for the paladin is actually the crusader, from *Tome of Battle*. *Tome of Battle* is easily the most tightly-balanced book in 3.5e, and its three classes (crusader, swordsage, and warblade) are all excellent additions to the game: they provide functional, enjoyable support for three major archetypes that were extremely underwhelming in core (as implemented by paladin, monk, and fighter).

I still let a crusader use the Pathfinder smite, though. After all, they only get 2 uses per day, and the 3.5e smite is not worth remembering you have.

1. <sub>As opposed to those who just want 2 levels for divine grace.</sub>
2. <sub>Unless you count the changes to polymorph effects as a “single” change.</sub>
3. <sub>The smite is actually worth getting more of, mercies are far better than the insulting *remove disease* *x*/**week** of the 3.5e paladin, and auras fill in dead levels with decent enough abilities.</sub>
4. <sub>In Pathfinder proper, usually to oracle. In 3.5e, there are a lot of good options but no single stand-out choice as good as oracle.</sub>

Comment: Mono-classed Paladins in Pathfinder get very generous features by martial standards. even after level 2. They get auras, immunities, divine bond (animal companion or magic weapon), spellcasting, channel energy, full BAB, Mercies to remove condition, and the continual advancement of Smite, Lay on Hands, etc. I wouldn't want players to read this and feel they need to multiclass for even more power...

Comment: @user56480 I know—and the footnote alludes to that—but “by martial standards” is a rather low bar, and not necessarily the appropriate standard by which to judge. Magic and martial characters are meant to play together, so they should all be judged on the same scale. That makes the paladin look much worse off.